Latest ubuntu/kubuntu 24.04 usb installer stick won't boot - initramfs error
This is a duplicate, but when I tried to comment on the original about the recommended fix not working for me, I wasn't allowed.  And when I tried to post as a answer, somebody deleted my post.  So, if this is not the right way to address this issue, could you direct me to a better way?  Thanks.
Anyway, like another poster, the 24.04 live installer won't boot on my old'ish (HP P7-1380T) desktop.  Gets an initramfs error and freezes the system.  This system runs Kubuntu 22.04 fine, and I'm typing this on that system booted from the latest KDE Neon live installer - which is also based on Ubuntu 22.04.  Oh, and I successfully installed from the Kubuntu 24.04 medium on 2 different Dell laptops.
I tried the recommended fix on my HP box (copying the ISO to my USB stick using mkusb both in live-only and persistent mode), but no luck.  In live-only mode I get the same initramfs problem.  In persistent mode, it gets pretty far into the boot process and then gets a hard fault and freezes.
I guess I'm stuck.  I could stick with 22.04 or go with KDE Neon, but eventually, Neon will probably re-base on a newer Ubuntu, which would likely fail to install too (and in any case, I'd prefer Kubuntu).
Since other people are having the same problem, I'm wondering whether anyone at Canonical is attempting to address it.  Is this even considered a bug - or is my old system just considered no longer supported?  Just asking...  Also, is it possible that the latest Ubuntu installation images just need more than the 4GB of memory my system has in order to work? Again, this system works well as is under 22.04.

Y'know what, I must've signed on differently when I tried to comment on the other post.  It said I didn't have enough reputation points, but I see that in fact I do.  Should I go back an add a comment to the original?  I'll leave this here for not.

How much RAM? If not 8GB, better to use a lightweight flavor. 4GB may be ok if SSD for faster swap file. And then use partition, not default install. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors) I happen to like Kubuntu which is more mid-weght but with external SSD I got 24.04 to work on 2006 laptop.

I sounds like minus the unneeded stuff your actual issue is you did not make the USB boot media correctly.  After downloading a fresh copy of the ISO follow the steps on this link to make sure that the ISO is good. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

I did verify the SHA256 checksum.  And, as noted, I was able to install from the same USB stick onto 2 different laptops.

@oldfred Any way to verify that memory is my issue?  I just checked, and the older of the 2 laptops I was able to install on does have 8GB, so maybe the 4GB on my desktop is the problem.

Do not know latest Ubuntu. With 20.04 could not install Ubuntu at all on old laptop with 1.5GB of RAM. Server installed and was able to use 24.04 Kubuntu on external SSD on both old laptop and new laptop. And SSD was copy of Kubuntu from my desktop. Try lighter weight flavor.
